# Why does Stack Overflow encourage people to downvote?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

Why does Stack Overflow encourage downvoting newbie's questions which don't meet their quality standards?

So by doing that, does it provide any answer to their questions? It might be protecting its own standards, but since Stack Overflow here is to help the users with their problems, isn't it good to be less restrictive for newbies till they get used to what all these rules are?

Comment: If we don't downvote them, how are they to know that what they have posted isn't acceptable?

Comment: :D just like that I know. Don't need a practical situation here :D

Comment: And what is the question format error in this question?

Comment: keep in mind downvotes here are different, they are acceptance/rejection or agree/disagree, not quality/clarity like on the main site.

Comment: `till they get used to what all these rules` are you suggesting new users cant read the FAQs, helps or guidelines?

Comment: yes i need more

Comment: @Plutonix did you read those crazy guidelines the very first day you wanted to ask a question?

Comment: @user3580271 You clicked a button confirming that you read them before you were able to ask your first question.  If you choose to ignore that, not look at any other questions, or make any attempt to figure out what an acceptable question looks like, then you are the one responsible for the consequences, not anyone else.  The site works *very hard* to lead new users into asking good questions; sadly, most are simply too determined to ask bad questions.  For those users, there isn't much to do beyond get rid of it as fast as possible.

Comment: absolutely. and I spent 2 hours wordsmithing the question.  I knew the question would very likely be read by the world's foremost expert on the subject, so I wanted it understood what I had tried and what the issue was.  If you go to someone's house for dinner and take a dump on the floor, why should you be surprised if they dont like you or dont invite you back?

Comment: @Plutonix Unless they're into that sort of thing! ;)

Comment: for the record, "Worlds Foremost Expert" in this case was played by Mark Gravell.  On a scale of userNNNNNN to Skeet, the question was "only" a Gravell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)

Comment: some people may quit if there is no downvote button :)

Comment: this poor guy was blasted 42 times and counting by the downvote. Kind of validates part of his question. though I have to admit this is hilarious.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do we really need reputation and upvotes/downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340174/do-we-really-need-reputation-and-upvotes-downvotes)

Answer (score 48):

> How do SO encourage to downvote for newbies questions which doesn't meet quality standards?

It doesn't, really, which is why too many poor quality questions don't attract any, or enough, downvotes.

People that downvote downvote because of intrinsic motivation to do so, not extrinsic motivation.  They inherently want to provide feedback on the quality of posts they read, they want to see the quality standards of the site upheld.  They don't need the site to reward them for providing this valuable feedback.

> So by doing that does it provide any answer to their questions?

Well, technically, a question can be downvoted and answered.  It actually happens a lot.  It's closing a question (which is also something that there really isn't much in the way of encouragement to do) that prevents answering.

> but since SO here is to help the users with their problems

No, SO is *not* here to help *individual* users with their problems.  It is here to create a useful repository of high quality questions and answers so that the entire programming community can benefit by being able to search through that repository of knowledge to solve their problems *without needing to actually ask another person for help*.

SO happens to, as a beneficial *side effect*, help users with their problems, when they are able to ask a question that happens to help SO accomplish it's *actual* goal.

> isn't it good to be less restrict for newbies till they get used to what all these rules are?

No.  First off, if we don't enforce our guidelines it greatly hampers the ability of the site to accomplish its goal.  Second, if we don't inform users when their questions are not up to our standards, they won't know that they even need to improve, let alone how, so they *won't*.  This means that either the quality standards are never enforced and the site becomes like every other site it was designed to compete with that just doesn't work, or it means that the guidelines get enforced later on for users, and they get hit with a brick wall wondering why all of a sudden the questions that are just like those they were asking the day before are suddenly not being answered.

Comment: This is very ineresting. I spent quite a long time on SO and never noticed that its goal is NOT to help people to find answers for their programming questions. If it is truth, than clearly it is not communicated enough. First sentence of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is "How do I ask a good question? We’d love to help you.". This with the rest of the text strongly suggest that the site here to *help people to get their questions answered*. If it not that that page should be updated.

Comment: @gorn How is "we'd like to help you ask a good question" in any way conflicting with these goals?

Comment: In your post you specifically say that "SO is not here to help individual users with their problems" which is conflicting with how SO communicates it's intents. SO looks like a place where you can get answers for your questions. If it is not the case, that it should be communicated better. I personally think that your can not say that the intent of creating database of reusable questions is superficial to the intent of helping people answering their questions.

Comment: @gorn People do as questions and they do get them answered.  It is a pleasant side effect of the *actual* mission of the site.  It happens, yes, but it is not the purpose of the site or its primary goal.  Of course, for a new user to the site they are unlikely to *care* about any of that, which is why it's not emphasized early on in the help center.  There are more important things to convey in the limited attention span that we have.

Comment: Is there ANY place which states this not very apparent intent? This page is about downvotes. I think that unless what you are saying is true and communicated to users than (uncommented) downvotes will (an can not) be regarded as action serving to ANY positive agenda. If you say (by downvote) "There is something wrong with your question" and neither the downvoter not the site itself gives any clue WHAT might be wrong, than the downvote is not good concept.

Answer (score -4):

For everyone saying a downvote keeps quality up... how about next time posting a comment on what can get done better.

Comment: please consider giving a read to [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/839601)

Comment: I have and I still don't get it.