# How to deal with mob voting

Tags: discussion, voting, downvotes, asking-questions

*I see this quite a lot, and feel "some frustration" with the results so I'd like to ask what if anything can be done about it. I am of course fully aware that users are free to vote however they please, and [recent discussions on why SO is so negative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late).*

---

Frequently I'll come across questions which appear to be downvoted into the ground for no real reason. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23648848/3) (subsequently edited), which when I first visited the question had 6 downvotes and no upvotes.

(*There are also - especially in the php tag it seems - frequent examples of the opposite: utterly trivial questions, receiving bewildering numbers of upvotes.*)

When downvoting a question, the tooltip shown is:

> This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or it is not useful

Granted, this question could show some more research effort (looking at the api for the functions involved) - but it's not IMO a bad question, I wouldn't go as far as to call it a good question but it does include:

- the code the question is about
- minimal attempt at debugging
- the error received
- the expected result (implicit)

So, it was in fact much better than many questions, all the components to answer the question are present - As should also be evident from the answer that was given. I would have just edited the question to make it more obvious what the problem was, which someone did after this question was asked.

### Are downvotes abused?

It seems that all too often the reason for downvoting are not inline with what Stack overflow's objectives they are from my perception:

- I don't like your question
- I don't understand the problem, which must mean no one else will either
- I don't agree with what you're doing, even though it may have little bearing on the question
- I think there are more important problems than what you've asked (not to be confused with X/Y problems)
- I know nothing about this but the question already has a negative score

This seems to be one of the many ways in which new users get a rough ride on SO, or perhaps one of the many ways new-ish users exercise their new found freedom when they obtain vote down privileges.

Is there anything that can be done to counter or reduce what I perceive as disproportionate voting?

*I'm not asking for justification of votes for this particular example but rather suggestions for anything that can be done when a question has what looks like a disproportionately large +/- score for the question itself*.

Comment: I can see why the question got downvoted. Presentation counts for a lot. There's very little in the way of explanation. Answerers have to put extra effort into fitting together the pieces. It's only slightly better than "My code doesn't work" followed by a code dump.

Comment: See also `(1)` [Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251487/456814) and `(2)` [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/456814).

Comment: I have just experienced this on a question I asked (ah, the question you mentioned) and subsequently been banned for no real reason other than people getting involved in things that don't concern the question at hand. Shows the way this site is heading.

Comment: The question presented as example contains a glaring security issue. Some consider this justification enough for a downvote. I don't recall voting down questions on the basis of security issues but I can see where those who choose to downvote on this basis are coming from.

Comment: @user2656114 if you revise your question to improve the presentation and give more context, people can remove their downvotes and/or make an upvote.

Comment: As I said, the comments are nothing to do with the question I asked. It is a bunch of people assuming things that don't concern the actual question. Why should I change my question?

Comment: @user2656114: you don't get banned for one question, but for a history of contributions that aren't received well.

Comment: @user2656114 trust me, your question could be improved a lot, it will help.

Comment: @AD7six sorry, it looks like the comments are going to get derailed into two threads, one addressing your original question in general, and the other about that one particular user's question.

Comment: See also [How can we discourage over-downvoting on questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253227/456814).

Comment: Possibly related: `(1)` [How SO encourage people to downvote?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254063/456814) and `(2)` [Are the downvotes a problem in Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253467/456814).

Comment: @AD7six I don't know how much you know about Meta voting, but in case you're confused, please see [Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they *really* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254108/456814), and also the Meta section of [Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251488/456814).

Comment: @Louis A glaring security issue should not be justification enough for a downvote, but rather issue a comment or an answer. Even errors can be useful. The real problem is the bad presentation. After the edit of halfer it is kind of bearable but in the initial state the downvotes were justified, I would say.

Comment: If a question is more likely to be downvoted when it was downvoted before. <-- I would call this mob voting.

Comment: I just saw the revision history. The first revision was actually better than the 3rd one that I first saw...though it still could have been improved a lot by adding more context and explanation.

Comment: Seriously? The question you linked sucks. Op did not read the docs and didn't even think of printing the whole array, which would have instantly solved his problem. It also shows that op doesn't really grasp what an array is in php (ok, that's more phps fault than his). But still, I barely know php and instantly knew he just used the wrong key. Anyways, downvoted that question as it could have been solved by the very basic debugging technique of printing the variable contents, and thus severely lacks effort on ops part.

Comment: [Is it possible on MSO to question something that people hold dear without getting “disagreement downvoted”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208876/165773)

Comment: @gnat thanks, [I'll add that to my list later](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254460/456814) (or you're welcome to, if you want).

Comment: @SList I'd support a must-have-a-question-mark filter =)

Comment: @Louis If I downvoted every question (instead of commenting or mentioning in the answer) I found with a security problem - I'd do nothing but issue downvotes. I consider downvoting for that reason alone somewhat selfish. The question was asked by one person, with the site objective of being the answer to all other users in the future who are looking for the solution to a similar problem. Downvoting the question for what is an unrelated problem is effectively unconstructive and prevents or disuades people with the same problem finding or reading that answer.

Comment: @AD7six, re: security, [there's an essential comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648848/oci-fetch-array-does-not-return-expected-column-data-in-php#comment36322241_23648848) under the question, that could have prevented lots of noise.

Comment: @AD7six I got sick and tired of staring at the question in the state it was in, it offended my brain too much, so I fixed it up **A LOT** and voted to reopen. Go ahead and vote it you want to.

Comment: ***Nice*** edit, @Cupcake. Kudos.

Comment: Downvoting on the basis of security issues like in that question is **VERY** wrong. It could also have been ironed out in another piece of code unrelated with the one posted in the question.

Comment: Revision 3 is a terrible question, its very lazy, we are not here to read your mind.  I would have downvoted it. Revision 5 is a great example of how to properly ask a question.  I would have upvoted it except I've already run out of votes today.

Comment: There is no extra info in revision 5 - which is why for me I find terrible-> good so hard to understand. Normal->good I _could_ understand.

Comment: If a questions gets 1 downvote, it's not hard to believe that it may end up with 20 if 20 people view it and come to the same conclusion.

Comment: @KevinB I don't believe that's what happens though more like "Hmm. Dunno but 10+ other people down-voted this I won't bother thinking about it -1".

Comment: I disagree with that. I'm sure it's possible that happens sometimes, but i doubt it's often.

Comment: I'm learning to only post material that might get me downvoted as a comment, which cannot be downvoted no matter how idiotic it is. Some folks here (in this comment thread) are masters of this technique, and since their rep scores are good it's probably wise to emulate them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few things you can do, but ultimately there's no way to "fight the mob".

Options:

### Edit the question

If a question is clear to you and you feel that others "just don't get it" - you can edit the question to make the intent more obvious. Presentation *does* count for a lot and to some more than others.

Of course, there's no telling whether existing voters will come back and/or agree with the edit - but a question aught to be judged on it's merits by new visitors at least.

### Vote/comment

If cleaning the question up isn't appropriate or it's too much effort, you can instead exercise your normal community rights and comment/vote on the question as you see fit.

### Or shrug it off and find a better question

There's no way to influence the masses, so ultimately the only thing an individual can do is learn from the experience (*next time, I'll hard code that sql statement that's irrelevant to the question, so I don't get 20 downvotes for my home movie library app that only I use being insecure!*) move on and look for or write better questions in the future.

Answer (score 15):

> Granted, this question could show some more research effort (looking at the api for the functions involved) - but it's not IMO a bad question.

I disagree - a lot.
There is no question, it is simply a statement followed by a block of code. This is why it got down voted. Now you might be able to divine what the problem is for that - if you can then good on you, there is nothing stopping you from answering the question (that many down votes makes you a candidate for the [Reversal badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) if you get enough up votes).

> Is there anything that can be done to counter or reduce what I perceive as unjust downvoting?

In its current state there are obviously a number of people who disagree with your judgement of the question. I would not call that mob voting at all.

> This seems to be one of the many ways in which new users get a rough ride on SO

Maybe. But it doesn't help when new users put in virtually zero effort for the expert free help they are seeking.

Comment: It has an accepted answer, so obviously there isn't any confusion on what the question was.

Comment: @user2656114 Regardless of whether someone could divine what the question was, it was a crap 'question'. The number and nature of the comments show this as well. I stand by what I said - there is no excuse for new users to not put any effort in. If they don't then they can expect down votes - simple.

Comment: I just saw the revision history. The first revision was actually better than the 3rd one that I first saw...though it still could have been improved a lot by adding more context and explanation.

Comment: `There is no question` - well, there is this "echo `$row['0'];` returns nothing." - which is "the question". The code to reproduce the problem is in the question, the error is in the question, the expected result is implicitly in the question - It doesn't require divine intervention in this example to see what the problem is; it only requires reading the question. Just by editing the wording on that line to "if I echo `$row[0]` I get nothing but I'm expecting my CUSTOMERNO value" the question, magically, becomes "clear" (I didn't edit it to ask this meta question).

Comment: @user2656114 think about it this way - Stack Overflow it 100% volunteer driven.  No one gets paid specifically to answer questions.  The experts on this site are here because they enjoy helping, but SO gets 8000 new questions per day.  Most of the the experts will focus their time on helping users that have shown some effort on their own, including the effort of making the question neat and presentable.  The downvoting is a signal to other users that the question isn't worth the time to look at, so go look at a different question.....

Comment: @user2656114  .... So basically what I'm saying is you *might* think the question is implicit, or clear, but you still didn't put enough effort into making it easy for other users to figure out the question.  Presentation can take a poor question and turn it into a pretty good one very easily.

Comment: " In its current state there are obviously a number of people who disagree with your judgement of the question." So now we not only have a flood of poor questions, we also have to endure people *whineing* when the bad questions are downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

> - I don't like your question
> - I know nothing about this but the question already has a negative score

Those aren't very good reasons, agreed.

> - I don't understand the problem, which must mean no one else will either

The downvote button is titled *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. Clear questions can be properly and quickly answered (and most likely a duplicate already exists), where unclear questions lead to speculation and equally unclear or unhelpful answers and question-and-answer games in comments, so a downvote is in order.

> - I don't agree with what you're doing, even though it may have little bearing on the question
> - I think there are more important problems than what you've asked (not to be confused with X/Y problems)

By explaining how to solve the underlying problem that prevents the problem at hand entirely, OP is helped as a developer. If they just want someone else to fix their syntax error and not think along with their code and won't actively participate in enhancing their question quality, they've come to the wrong site.

Granted, both reasons justify a downvote, but a comment explaining so would really help OP. I'm not in favor of a mandatory comment for downvoting though, I would then expect it to be mandatory for upvotes too.

Comment: Regarding "solve the underlying problem": The thing is, in this example does fixing the sql injection vulnerability address the question being asked? Would it magically make `$row` not an empty array? The answer is no, so while definitely worth mentioning it's not "the problem". On the bright side, the OP was bombarded with flippant comments to let them know their code was insecure and feel rosy about it.

Comment: I'm also not in favour of mandatory comment for downvoting, perhaps anonymous statistics or something - "1: Did you read the docs 3: your code is insecure 10: I don't have perms yet to vote to close". Would give some further meaning to the OP as to what's wrong with their question - and how to fix it (and stop speculation as to why people are voting when there aren't comments).

Comment: "solve the underlying problem" only applies to beginner programmers, and is otherwise an excuse for directing anger at the OP for daring to ask a problem the downvoter cannot understand.

Comment: @simon that is not true, many people have trouble describing what they actually want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As the person that provided the accepted answer to the linked question (gee, all the potential for my first reversal badge if I get another 14 upvotes) I didn't find it particularly difficult to diagnose the problem from the question, so (while the OP could easily have answered it themself simply by reading the docs).... what I found harder was identifying the second issue that's answered in the comments to my answer.

If the OP had read the docs, or done some basic debugging they could easily have solved this themselves; but the second issue was slightly harder to spot (especially with the couple of edits to the question).... but it certainly didn't justify as many downvotes as it received IMO.... given the increasing number of bad questions on SO, this did provide code, and did provide enough detail to identify the problem(s) even though it wasn't particularly well expressed.... it was far better than a "give me the codez" or an "it don't work" question.

And I still believe that any downvote, whether against a question or an answer, deserves a comment explaining why, and allowing the poster the opportunity to improve their question (or their answer). IMO, forcing somebody to justify a downvote in a comment might lose their anonymity, but potentially help the original poster to see how their question (or answer) could be improved.

To my mind, that would help improve the quality of questions (and answers) on SO; help posters learn how to improve their questions to the point where they were more useful for posterity as well, and prevent block downvoting before they have had the opportunity to improve their question. And it wouldn't turn away as many newcomers to the board if those downvotes were perceived as proactively trying to help them improve the quality of their questions.

Comment: Even if it is just a case of the _first_ downvoter must leave a comment explaining why, it gives that opportunity to improve the question before mob downvoting mentality prevails

Comment: How exactly was this better than a "it don't work" question? This is IMO the very definition of this type of question; OP stated his problem without doing basic debugging or reading the docs. I agree that one should comment (given no similar comment exists) in such a case, as long as the question isn't completely hopeless, and I also agree that this is far from the worst questions on SO and could even considered good relative to most other questions in the php tag, but that doesn't change the fact that it's still a bad question...

Comment: Perhaps it's my definition of an "it didn't work" question.... I see enough, particularly under the PHP tag, where the question is simply "I wrote a script and it didn't work".... without any code; or error messages, or indication of what was expected, or even an explanation of whether "didn't work" means blank page or wrong data displayed or an error/exception message or anything.... this had enough code to diagnose the problem

Comment: `the second issue was slightly harder to spot` - I doubt (m?)any voters read/understood well enough to get that far. The php tag is a great example of bad "it doesn't work" questions for sure =) thanks for joining in on meta.

Comment: Ok, so your definition encapsulates the absolutely horrible questions where OP lacks the basic common sense to figure out people on SO can neither read minds nor read his code if he doesn't include it in the question. But while this question is certainly not as awful, it is still by all means a bad question... just because your tag is overrun with even more horrible stuff doesn't mean you should lower the accepted standards, because that's a very slippery slope.

Comment: But simply massive downvoting without explanation of why (which can happen with any tag) doesn't help anybody.... at least an explanation of why a post is downvoted gives an opportunity for the poster to improve.... bad questions can be made better if the poster is shown why its bad; if they're not shown, then nothing is ever likely to change

Comment: @l4mpi That all sounds quite elitist IMO. (Again, bear in mind this is one example of many) Should the Author have done more work - for sure. Should they be aware of functions like `print_r` - definitely. Should simple questions not be asked on Stack Overflow (look at what the _actual_ problem was) - absolutely not. Stack overflow isn't a site only for hard/interesting problems.

Comment: @AD7six how is this elitist? I'm not proposing to instantly ban OP or anything, I'm just saying it's a bad question as it shows little to no research or debugging effort (which you seem to agree on). Thus it should be downvoted. Which is again not elitist, but simply stating that we expect OP to invest more of their own time BEFORE asking on SO. And Mark, I already said one should of course comment - I've got 5k downvotes and probably commented on >75% of them, upvoted existing comments on 90% of the rest, and only silently moved on when the question was so bad I wanted to punch my monitor...

Comment: `it shows little to no research or debugging effort (which you seem to agree on)` - No, I don't agree. It could demonstrate _more_ debugging effort; a (blinkered) debugging effort was made. But anyway, that's almost off topic, my question isn't about an individual's reasoning but what I perceive as mob-driven voting.

Comment: `my $array has length 1 but $array['0'] isn't set isn't all that hard to debug` - apparently you haven't understood the question. read @MarkBaker's answer (and the comments to his answer). I simply disagree that noobs should be downvoted for being noobs; demonstrating _some_ effort is a world apart from demonstrating no effort - they can be helped/guided.

Comment: @AD7six yeah, seems like I misread the question; but my point still stands - any more debugging (printing the result of the fetch calls) would have solved the question. And as for `noobs being downvoted for being noobs` - you've got this entirely wrong. People are getting downvoted for not fulfilling the expected quality standards of StackOverflow. If they're new to SO/programming/the internet or not should not make any difference at all in the way you are voting. After all, a bad or unresearched question doesn't suddenly become good or well-researched just because OP is a noob...

Comment: It was a simple question that needed a simple answer (and it got it within a few minutes) - no mob required, that's all. But, I got my answer, and it made 9 or so e-Penis's larger, so we're all happy.

Comment: @CodeCaster Everybody has time to complain about bad questions, to look at these questions, and to downvote these questions- yet they don't have time to say why the question deserves a downvote? I agree that a comment or even a tick box of what the problem was out of a few general options would be useful here.