# Dealing with My Own Over Reactions (formerly known as Dealing with Mob Mentality)

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users, behavior

**Edit**
After some recent heated activity here on Meta, I've had some time to reflect upon what is important here and what is maybe, splitting hairs and I think that this post is of the latter.  It has really put into perspective for me, what is more or less universally offensive.

I've since joined in one of the chat rooms to help clear up the close vote review queue and I'm enjoying the community and working with constructive members in ways that suit my activities here. I think this will be a much better way of improving things here, than posting on Meta with over emotional reactions to what I perceive as unfairness to the underdog, so to speak.

It's time to focus on the good things in the community and have faith in our strength as a community to rid the community of any real threats to our community, rather than keep monitoring the pulse for any changes. For if I continue to do that, I will only alienate myself from the very community I love.

*I've left the original question in tack so the answers and comments make sense, except to anonymise the images.*

---

There are other questions that deal with similar issues: [How to deal with mob voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254810/how-to-deal-with-mob-voting) and there is a focus on the [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.

This is simply a discussion post to elucidate a mob mentality that is really distasteful and has no place on SO.

A new comer asks a question. One person jumps on this question and a stream of upvoted comments and banter ensues with a massive downvote of the question.

I have included screen shots below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Now here is linked an upvoted question that covers almost the same issue [Downloading/Caching Google Maps for Offline Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889080/downloading-caching-google-maps-for-offline-use?rq=1).

All I want to say is this type of barrage needs to stop. One comment, two maybe, but really how many times do people need to ridicule a newcomer?

Can't people ask themselves, is this comment constructive and raising the tone of the site, or is it an opportunity to show case wit and ridicule another.. or whatever lies between on the spectrum.

**TLDR**

When there is a stream of comments and downvotes upon a question, what is the best way to circumvent what is perceived as mob mentality?

In this case I commented, found an answer and flagged the comment thread. If anyone else has any better ideas, it would be good to hear them.

Comment: 'Now here is linked an upvoted question that covers almost the same issue from 2011'.

Comment: I fail to see where anyone is breaking the "Be Nice" policy.  No one is being rude.  Downvoting and voting to close off-topic questions is not being rude.  And none of the comments seem especially problematic.

Comment: The downvotes aren't tied to the comments. The question you highlighted tagged the questions as `c`, `c#` and `google-maps`. Those three tags have over 135K followers. It's entirely possible that the question was downvoted for not having anything to do with c or c#

Comment: Also note: 'I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about legal issues aren't on-topic for SO'

Comment: Also, if there IS rudeness involved, it's on meta.  The implication that I just downvote such questions without reading them, following some mob like some drug-crazed protestor, is grossly insulting.  I've just about had it with the way SO contributors are casually slagged off, both in SO main and meta.

Comment: Both of those questions are horrible examples. The questions are blatantly off-topic, and I see nothing that goes against the Be Nice policy in the comments. While the pile of comments is completely unnecessary noise, we have far more complaints when posts get massively downvoted and no comments are left at all.

Comment: If you see rude comments, flag them and moderators will review. I've cleaned up a few of these (the first comment wasn't particularly constructive, and other comments duplicated things that had been said by others), but they did have a point. This seems to be a Google licensing issue, which is outside of the scope of this site. The comments that pointed out that this had nothing to do with the language tags used were also valid and not rude, although I see the asker rolled back the edits that removed the [c] tag.

Comment: @BradLarson yes, thanks for handling the flags. I think the first comment was rude and set the tone.. so adding, 'asking a random people on the internet' made an otherwise reasonable comment a throw away remark. And it's the upvoting of the comments and the OPs reaction, to a newcomer, it is abrasive and I think it's unnecessary. But there seems to be a wide difference of opinion of what is 'rude', I realise. I think when someone is new to a community, it's better to be polite. Even if they're off-topic. My point is, how likely is that person to return?

Comment: I had no intention of ridiculing the OP.  I was responding to the poster of 'This is a reasonable question about using the Google maps api'.  True/false?  Who knows, but that is irrelevant since it's off-topic for SO.

Comment: Abrasive?  Why is it that question posters can cheat and lie with impunity, but SO contributors must avoid being honest in case it's 'distasteful'?

Comment: @MrsEd It's a very sad reality that you are in fact correct that an aberration for a low quality to actually get downvoted, to go along with the polite comments explaining why it's not an appropriate question.  All too often people just upvote the very low quality questions instead..

Comment: To prevent mobbing comments we have a simple [guideline](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation) in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room: *A post is only actively edited/commented/handled by one member of the room. We don't need 4 members all leaving witty statements in the comments or in chat.*

Comment: @rene That's something we should do on Meta as well. When someone asks "Why don't we make comments mandatory on downvotes?" (or whatever annoying repost of repost), only one person should answer them.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: No, those questions shouldn't be answered, they should just be closed as dupes.

Comment: @Cerbrus Or that. I meant for the prolonged discussions that typically follow in comments.

Comment: You seem to have an issue with the phrase "random people on the internet", which I don't understand at all. It's a standard phrase, and it's not even _remotely_ about the OP (and it's pretty hard to see anyone who it is about -- everyone else, i.e. -- getting upset about it: again, standard phrase, with no negative connotation at all). Can you suggest a way this could have been written that you would perceive differently?

Comment: Also, note that this comment was left because it was used as a custom close vote reason, which is the only means available to specify "completely off topic" in the close dialog.

Comment: There are still plenty of SO users that are passionate and protective of SO.  That question is the equivalent of a new neighbor walking his dog and letting it do its business on your front porch.  It is literally a turd of a question.  They responded a lot more constructive than most regular people would.  Dismissing such passion as "mob behavior" is very toxic, please stop doing that.  If you don't like the way people act at SO then you can surely find a better place on the world wide web to spend your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I kind of understand where you were coming from. Even if the comments aren't overtly abusive, there's really no need to be the 5th or 6th person to pile on.

At a certain point, the point has been made, and there's no need to beat a dead horse...

Occasionally when I see this behavior I'll leave a comment to that effect. Something along the lines of:

> Someone has already explained what's wrong with the post, there's no need to carry on here.

Other times when things start to go off the rails I'll just drop a custom moderator attention flag:

> Things are getting a little out of hand in the comments here, and they
>   may need to be purged.

The flagging option often yields positive results. Moderators usually seem to be *happy<sup>1</sup>* to clear the wreckage and handle the post appropriately, and it spares you the time and aggravation of being pulled into the mess.

**With that said... Please remember to vote to close questions that aren't a good fit for the site, many times the quickest way to stop a feeding frenzy is to put a post out of its misery.**

<sub><sup>1</sup>Not sure how happy they are about it, but it's their job... so...</sub>

Comment: I like the post foot note :)

Answer (score 35):

This question isn't about a programming problem, but it's a legal question about the usage of an API.

To quote [the help center:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

The subject of these questions meets none of those bullet points. As such, they are in fact off-topic for SO.

They should probably be closed. They're also bound to receive some downvotes.
Now, in the linked examples, no-one is being rude. The comments are to the point, leaving out any personal opinions.

<sup>(As of right now, they have been closed)</sup>

The only problem (in my *opinion*), is that you're linking to a post from *2011* as an example why the screencapped question should stay open.

Back then, the rules were different. That question is no longer on-topic for SO, and as such, I've voted to close it.

---

Now, this meta question on the other hand implies most users that vote, vote without reading anything, just because *"that's what everyone does"* ("Mob mentality")

Most users I know of at very least *skim* posts before posting. Implying mob mentality is... Not very nice.

Comment: In fairness, I don't think she is using as an example of why to keep it open since she presumably voted to close as a duplicate (based on the "possible duplicate" comment on the actual post),

Comment: Maybe the first comment is borderline?

Comment: @rene: I can agree to that. But then again, I think it's common courtesy to research a bit before asking on SO. I'm not familiar with google's documentation on the subject, but _if_ the answer is relatively easy to find in there, this question indicates a lack of research.

Comment: @rene probably closest to rude of all of the comments, agreed.

Comment: The mob mentality is aimed at people who upvote rude comments and become drawn into making comments that are not helpful. e.g. the asking for legal help comment is not bad, but adding asking random people off the internet is facetious and unnecessary. This is a newcomer and one faulty question doesn't mean they have nothing to contribute. The Op him/herself commented on not feeling welcome. So I am going by this. Commenting on a handful of people's behaviour is not deeming it to be across the whole community. Anyway, thanks for the answer, I agree with most of it.

Comment: How is agreeing with a comment a symptom of _"Mob mentality"_? If I see a comment I like, for whatever reason, I upvote it. The same for downvotes. Current vote count shouldn't be a factor in a user's decision wether or not, and how to vote for it.

Comment: The original question was never on topic.

Comment: Aren't we all random people off the internet? We don't go for beers nor go out, I don't know anyone here personally, I might recognize their usernames, but that doesn't mean I know them.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to circumvent mob mentality is to simply ask:

a) a good question

b) a question that fits nicely into the sites guidelines.

Comment: Also, a question that shows that you've done even the most basic of research (though, I'd expect this to fall under "a good question")

Comment: Yes, but that will not help. If you decide that a question fails either test, and so you downvote it, you are still a vicious, uncaring malicious voter who downvotes newbs without any consideration. following the mob mindlessly.   It doesn't matter if you are justified, you are guilty:(

Comment: @MartinJames Didn't you know that it's *imperative* that people who post low quality questions need to be treated with kid gloves, and you can't so much as *blink* around them for fear of offending them, but there's nothing wrong with insulting people that politely ask for, and expect, questions to meet the site's quality standards, slandering them with entirely baseless accusations, etc. because they're not actually people.

Comment: If you ask a good enough question, you'll get mobbed with good answers and upvotes.  How is this helping prevent mob mentality at all?! ;-)

Comment: Step 1: Be an very experienced programmer who only has great questions.  Step 2: ask them.

Answer (score 4):

After a prolonged period of seeking to affect positive change or awareness utilizing Meta, I have decided to hang up those cleats. It simply was an ineffective and ill-suited conduit in retrospect.

As I have a deep sense of attachment to SO that I wish to maintain, I have changed my focus. I will be concentrating my efforts on helping to keep the Q&A quality as clean as possible with the few resources that I can bring to bear. Primarily through the efforts of the close vote reviewers and related efforts of awareness. 
We all have a common love for the good that SO embodies. I will do my best at being fair and balanced in maintaining that.

Comment: Trying to change anything here is like shouting at the wind. This site is lost irredeemably. And soon enough AI will replace all of it.