# Does SO really not care about its users?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, behavior

One of the user with quite a high reputation comented on my other post the following:

> Remember: On SO we don't care about the users and their feelings. We care about quality posts, that is where the voting is for. If you don't like that distinction or rather have a user-oriented site find another site because SO is not going to change that. This site is huge due to the focus on content instead of trying to cater for any user. – rene 27 mins ago

I am really shocked to learn it and wants the senior users to clarify if this the culture of such a reputed website?

Comment: What the user meant to say that we have a culture of critiquing and sorting out incorrect content, and that that counts more to us than coddling the author's feelings. Pretty much like in any other field that values quality knowledge, e.g. academia. If you read something into this that "shocks" you then you should probably explain to us what that is, exactly.

Comment: @pekka having constructive conversation is always healthy since we learn something. I am not asking any personal favour. SO say we should not make personal attack. But he is asking me to leave the site in a way. Is this the way to treat community members?

Comment: That is not at all what he is saying. All he's saying is we put content before people. And votes are all about the content.

Comment: @Raider: Discussions are not, and never were, in SO's scope. Comments only have two sanctioned purposes: Asking for clarification, and suggesting improvements. And even comments for that purpose were late-comers to the party.

Comment: My other questions been marked duplicate and in very second coment I accepted it already. And you already know I offered to close that conversation then why he started all this over again?

Comment: May be I used discussion In wrong context. What I mean is asking for and providing clarification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On large communities decaying over time, being nice or mean, and Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow)

Comment: @Raider - do you realize that a very large number of SO question posters are incompetent, bone-idle, selfish, indolent deadbeats whose sole intention is to abuse SO contributors by conning them into working for free?  This is usually called 'slavery' and it is illegal in many jurisdictions.  Instead of beating SO slaves who refuse to follow orders, posters of bad SO questions make constructive advice a personal issue and moan about personal affronts on meta.  I call these people 'slave drivers'.

Comment: Raider, I understand why you might see this for reason of concern, I really do, *however* it's one comment taken from a zillion on here and out of context. I for one (and you can check my profile) an known to jump up and down when I see things on here I don't like, and Rene helped me by pointing to a chat room and a community which has made me feel more a part of the community and a room that is dedicated to being fair and nice. So I would give it some more time to look around before jumping in with one example (please look at my posts and you will see I have been similar).

Comment: I can't answer here, so have a look here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311853/3956566

Comment: @MartinJames that's more properly called fraud, not slavery :/

Answer (score 26):

I made that comment to clarify that the voting that takes place on Stack Overflow is on the merit of the posts and in no way targeted at users. Your previous question seemed to be about that topic.

To make that distinction very clear I like to use an hyperbole. It looks like I succeeded in that.

Let me link to the the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Notice how it doesn't say: *we are a friendly group of people that are here to help with what ever you ask, just try it*.

There are enough other sites that offer that kind of one-on-one support are also flourishing. On Stack Overflow however that is very much different and it is a difference I very much like and appreciate.

It is not my intention to scare you away and I'm a deep believer of the [be nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) but I also don't want to give false impressions. We don't cater for a single OP, we aim to have a useful knowledge base without chit chat and distractions that aims at helping many, many future visitors.

To make sure those future visitors keep returning to Stack Overflow we need to strive for quality on the posts. The personal approach is something that comes second.

Let me give one example  from yesterday which I feel demonstrates a bit what happens if you don't moderate content, this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/3vjeyq/stack_overflow_is_down_how_do_i_computer/cxo4dad). Everything goes, but the signal to noise ration is awful.

To conclude: You're more than welcome on Stack Overflow but we have a rather unique set of guidelines and distinct goal. If you can contribute well researched, interesting questions that will help future visitors that have similar problems Stack Overflow is a great site. The users that are more looking for instant answers without having the stamina to do some research or work themselves will have a hard time in becoming a successful member of this community. And I'm not going to give anyone the impression it is the other way around.

Comment: Rene I didn't like the wording used. We are all highly qualified how can we such a harsh on each other

Comment: We are most definitely not all highly qualified. If that were the case, no moderation would be needed.

Comment: Especially we I wanted to close it. I mentioned it in previous comment on that post

Comment: @Raider I stand by my comment and I don't think it was particular harsh but I'm glad you asked a question about it so I could elaborate a bit why I left that comment. I'll reference this answer in the future. Thanks for helping out in creating guidance for users that might have the wrong idea of what SO is for.

Comment: @rene I don't know may be I've taken it too personally.

Comment: That is for every individual different. It can be a bit daunting if all these users jump on the band wagon and start explaining stuff. Don't give up but also don't expect that the majority of users on meta will all of a sudden change the moderation policy. At meta I tend to be a little bit more direct then on main, after all [meta is murder](http://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/). I've grown a thicker skin over the years.

Answer (score 14):

> Do we, on SO, care about our users?

Yes, insofar as we strive for a professional and civil tone.
That *does not* in any way, shape or form mean compromising our tools for moderating the site and keeping its quality high, or diluting our comments with fluff to soften the blow.

No, insofar as having many users is not the site's goal. The site's goal is building a high-quality collection of all questions and answers on the topic of programming.
If you want to help with that goal, or helping you furthers it, you are welcome. If neither is the case, you are simply on the wrong site.

Comment: The thing is, that's an oxymoron, as `Yes, insofar as we strive for a professional and civil tone.` is in an of itself a fact that we do care! :D haha! +1 to you.