# Do we really need reputation and upvotes/downvotes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes, upvotes

Recently I asked a question I didn't realize was already answered because of using the wrong search term. As a result, people commented what likely happened and it got -7 in voting. I was okay with that.

Later, I encountered a problem much worse problem, and when I went to ask it, the down votes on that question and another question with a similar situation made it so I couldn't post for 5 days, and I really needed an answer. The tips they give haven't really helped without giving me more information on what I need to change. Call me whatever you want, but this is a real problem. Typically, when you ask a question you need an answer. If you can't ask a question when you need it, you more likely will forget about it when you can finally ask.

As for reputation, I understand they are trying to make a reward and encouragement of certain things, however after looking at the methods of getting it, for the most part, really reputation is more of a measure of how much you have gotten into the flow of SO than character like the rewards say it is. A  major part of Stack Overflow is to help programmers learn programming languages and become skilled at it.

Considering what the consequences of downvotes, low reputation, and the ranking system provided by upvotes and downvotes are, they go against that. Tell me your opinion, however very few of the pro-reputation arguments and pro-upvotes/downvotes arguments have been convincing to me.

Comment: The purpose of downvotes is to rate the quality of the content so that it can be properly sorted among the millions of questions on this site for future use. If you ask low quality or poorly researched questions, people will downvote them so that the higher quality questions show up first. If you have a history of asking poor quality questions, you won't be able to ask as often until you improve said history. Yes, i think we need repuation and upvotes/downvotes.

Comment: *"The point of stack overflow is to help programmers learn programming languages and become skilled at it."* [citation needed]

Comment: So, the "I really needed an answer" is NOT the right time to come to Stack. We build a repository of knowledge, not a help desk. If you are in an emergency, look for a consultant, don't come here :/. And you are entirely right, rep is a measure of how much "in the flow" of Stack you are. The more "in the flow" you are, the more rep you have. The more rep you have, the more privileges you have...

Comment: Consider though, even if we do need them, they appear to have harsher consequences than they need. Should something be done about this?

Comment: I mean.. it's not like you were banned from asking entirely after one bad question. It could certainly be worse. You never really get entirely banned from asking, the period between being able to ask is just increased.

Comment: @SebastiantheAwesome: search for "be nice" on Meta to see a lot of conversations around being welcoming to new posters. I am not sure the removal of the voting system is going to fly though - it does have some drawbacks, but the benefits greatly outweigh them.

Comment: While being unable to post can be harsh, I really have to wonder what you were asking that got 7 down votes.  I see terrible questions all the time and most only have 1 to 3 down votes.  I only usually see that many on things like spam.  Maybe people in tags I don't frequent are just more down vote happy, but that many down votes makes me skeptical that the votes were just for it being a duplicate question.

Comment: gee @CodeCaster all these philosophical smokescreens and all of this whining is (as usual) piled around one really simple issue: "I couldn't post for 5 days, and I really needed an answer" - and the duplicate addresses just that

Comment: I went to University, but didn't do very well. Do we really need courses, grades, and all those silly degrees?

Comment: @SebastiantheAwesome what "harsher" consequences than needed? Looking at one's history of posting and how it's been received by the community, an algorithm is slowing down your rate to give you time to look, learn, and better your next questions. To make sure you don't end up banned. It's actually VERY nice, considering it prevents you from falling in the "end state" rapidly.

Comment: @Pekka웃 You used to, before SO existed; now you can just post every problem your boss gives you there.

Comment: *"If you can't ask a question when you need it, you more likely will forget about it when you can finally ask."* ... You mean it wasn't really that important? Or, do you have a habit of forgetting important things?

Comment: @TinyGiant Look, what I'm trying to say is that the time given might be too long.

Comment: @SebastiantheAwesome Again, time has no meaning for Stack's goal. The goal is to build up a repo of knowledge. The algorithm slowing you down is to make sure your next question doesn't ALSO get downvoted (because you are in a rush and maybe won't make it as pristine as you should), so that you don't spam the site with questions that get downvoted and end up banned. Take the opportunity of this forced break to lurk on meta, read up on what makes a good question. by the time the 5 days are done, you will have a way better question

Comment: Also, if we can't remove anything, maybe change it? Often things might be  too long, especially if there are due dates. I'm not saying we should change the 5 days thing just to help a few users, but I'm saying there should be descisions involving this that comes closer to helping 100% of the user population.

Comment: @SebastiantheAwesome Okay, so why do you think it's too long?  What evidence do you have to suggest that shortening the times we delay users with a history of providing low quality content won't increase the amount of low quality content on the site?  If you expect to see a change, you need to support it, rather than just saying, "I don't like it".

Comment: @SebastiantheAwesome Why should we change it? No matter WHAT we change it to, there will be SOMEONE SOMEWHERE with a "shorter" deadline and will want it even shorter. In the end we won't have any rate limit anymore... At the end of the day, time has no bearing here, so we shouldn't adapt our algorithms for "people with deadlines". We do not cater to deadlines. Period.

Comment: I care deeply about the quality of content on this site and the future usability of this site. If we stopped moderating low quality content, it would quickly render all of the high quality content useless due to the sheer amount of low quality content drowning it out. We already have a hard enough time fighting back against the wall of crap that gets bigger each and every day. I do not care at all about your deadlines or the fact that you need help or want an answer, just like you obviously don't care at all about the quality of content on this site.

Comment: *especially if there are due dates.* Stack Exchange sites are not designed for time sensitive issues. If you need help in a hurry you need to ask someplace else.

Comment: If you want to be taken seriously, it's probably worth actually *participating* in the place in a meaningful way for a while before suggesting "everything should be done differently" type changes

Comment: @Pekka웃 A-friggin'-men to your most recent comment.

Comment: You think, that it is not important for you, or for everybody ? Becouse I disagry with you. Or you have idea better solution ?

Comment: see also: [It is time we abolish downvoting!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405582/839601)

Answer (score 36):

> The point of stack overflow is to help programmers learn programming languages and become skilled at it.

No, it's not. The [goal of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal) is to build a Q&A site containing high quality questions and answers. To ensure this quality, we need people to moderate the site. Even you, with 17 reputation, can moderate, by upvoting high quality content. Downvotes are necessary as well, to make sure low quality content is less visible.

Reputation is a measure of [trust](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), and as you gain more of this trust (by receiving upvotes), you will get access to more [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Answer (score 16):

> The point of stack overflow is to help programmers learn programming languages and become skilled at it.

That is a common misconception, and I sincerely wonder where it comes from.

It is a website that was, at least at one point in time, meant to contain the answer to every unique programming problem imaginable.

That some poor person having that question and asking it gets an answer so they can continue with their job or homework is a side-effect.

This site does not exist to help individual users.

That being said, yes, we do need a voting system. I couldn't care less about reputation points (perhaps easy for me to say), but the signals the votes (or at least downvotes) represent definitely need to stay. For *you* they haven't turned out that well, but frankly, that's *your* loss, because it means you haven't been playing nice with the way the site is intended to be used.

You may not know this, but the sheer amount of unanswerable or even unintelligible questions that is posted on this site a day is already unmaintainable. Without voting, there would be no way whatsoever to (automatically) flag users who repeatedly show that they don't understand how this site works.

Comment: I don't think I mind if a question only ever helps one user, especially in niche tags that get very little attention. If a question is detailed and has enough information to answer, and the poster has expended effort on it, I think it is good if it is answered.

Comment: (I suppose we can say though that good questions are _likely_ to help more than one person - we just do not know if they will!).

Comment: @halfer I'm not denying that. I also don't care whether an answer I type helps only one person or maybe many. It's just that a question has to have the _potential_ to be useful for many, not just the one.

Comment: That misconception is simply explained. When you learn a new language and wonder "hmmm how do I concatenate strings in this?" Most of the time, you fall on SO to find your answer. You quickly just think "hey, SO is the place to ask as you learn a new language". It definitely should not be this way, but I do think that people make that mental jump rather quickly...

Comment: "*I sincerely wonder where it comes from.*" That's easy to understand. Our most basic transaction involves someone having a problem and us giving them a solution to it. That's helping a person. It's not much of a stretch to move from that to believing that we're here to help any person with any programming problem, and that the solution ought to be tailored to that problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas BINGO. Which is why I often say that stack is a victim of its own success there.... No idea how to turn it back though:(

Comment: "The point of Stack Overflow is to help programmers" would have been perfectly valid. It's that last bit that is wrong. Stack Overflow is a *terrible* way to learn programming languages, and if you try to do it anyway, you will inevitably run into a lot of friction.

Answer (score 7):

> reputation is more of a measure of how much you have gotten into the flow of SO than character like the rewards say it is

I don't think it is. Not for me.

Many people on meta talk about "fake internet points" or "meaningless unicorn points" and such. But I don't think it's "fake" or "meaningless" at all.

Because for me, an upvote means I've helped someone.

Yesterday I got an upvote on an answer I provided two years ago.  You can never know the reason for a vote, but I think it's reasonably certain that they ended up there while trying to solve some problem, and that my answered helped them solve it.

Don't get me wrong, the current reputation system isn't perfect. Some people gain reputation even though they don't really "deserve" it, and others probably "deserve" a bit more. But on the whole, it works fairly well. Besides, in the end most of life is unfair, so Stack Overflow is hardly an exception here.

"Helping people" is not the prime reason I provide answers here, but it's certainly *a* reason. Positive feedback is always good. Of all my open source projects that I have on GitHub (>30), the one I spent the most time on over the years is the one I got the most feedback on (and also don't actually use a whole lot myself).

---

For questions, the up and downvotes do something a bit different. Trying to find interesting questions to answer can be pretty hard, and up/downvotes service a basic filter to weed out the worst of the questions.

It seems that your questions are now deleted. So I can't provide specific advice as to why exactly they got so many downvotes; but in general, they're for a reason. They were unclear, the duplicates were very easy to find, etc. Try to be open and constructive about that people tell you in the comments.

Comment: I agree with your perspective, but even if rep is just *"a measure of how much you have gotten into the flow of SO"*, that is also needed.  We don't want people who haven't invested time getting to know how the site works moderating content because their decisions might not be in line with the goals of the site.

Comment: Now that I've seen rep described as *"a measure of how much you have gotten into the flow of SO"* twice already, I'm beginning to see the value in them. The terrible "reputation" label just makes it hard to take them seriously.