# Why are proposed changes to voting, which limit or remove the use of downvotes, met with strong disagreement?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, faq-proposed

The comments and answers on many proposals to change the way voting works on Stack Overflow indicate there are strong opinions against many of these changes, mainly because such proposals alter the way downvotes can be used in various ways. Most such proposals to voting either restrict or remove downvotes from the system.

Why is there such disagreement when the concept of changing downvotes is raised?

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: Trying to imitate https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/792066 to list common reasons why proposals are met with strong disagreements. Lets see if it helps.

Comment: Excuse me, folks, but why somebody wants to close this as "needs details or clarity"? This is a FAQ-style self-answered question that is perfectly in line with how other meta FAQ entries look like.

Comment: I just don't see how it's different from [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)...

Comment: @Tomerikoo - I guess it would be beneficial to separate the FAQ on "why feedback is not necessary" and the FAQ on "why downvotes are a part of the content rating system" of SO. While the first one highlights one of the problems with voting (regardless of whether or not it is adequately solved), it does not question the downvoting as such. But, admittedly, a few posts do question the merits of downvoting per se, so I think it is time we have a FAQ on that (granted, the are bound to be some intersecting points)

Comment: @Useless any improvement that limits or removes the downvotes. That's already included in the "because it somehow alters the way that downvotes can be used".

Comment: @ilkkachu self answered questions are still bound to the quality standards. You should be able to answer this question _as is_. If you can't, then explain why you believe you can't, or edit the question to make it better.

Comment: I don't really get the slack the question is getting right now - isn't the whole point of FAQ questions to be concise statements of hypothetical situations not tied to any particular post/tag/user/whatever. The only thing I would change about how it is currently worded is to rephrase the last part as "why downvotes are considered to be an important part of the voting system" instead to avoid being seen as asking to speculate about why people disagree with such proposals.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no, there's nothing hypotetical about this situation: every question that ask for some kind of limit or restriction to downvotes are met with a strong disagreement. Below I list the common themes of _why_ (which the question asks) the disagreements occur.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi [This question also says "my"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin), nobody claims that is unclear. It's asking about a situation, but if that's your only complain, I can edit it to remove pronouns, but the situation remains.

Comment: I'm starting to believe FAQ stands for "Frequently Answered Questions", at this point...

Comment: _proposed changes to voting, which limit or remove the use of downvotes, met with strong disagreement_ What are those proposals? Can you link some examples?

Comment: @LuisMendo - isn't [the most recent one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405582) that started all this one such "proposal"? Not sure about the other ones, since it is likely a lot of them are deleted (which is a subject of the parallel discussion)

Comment: @OlegValter Thanks! I didn't know about it

Comment: @LuisMendo - NP, I think at this point it is nigh impossible to track what references what :)

Comment: @OlegValter You’re right: you could _try_ to keep up with everything, as I’m doing right now. I have a queue of comments to upvote, since I’m constantly running out of daily votes. I have several answers and comments yet to read. All the while keeping up with the outdated answers project. I don’t know why I like to follow drama this much… ‍♂️

Comment: I clicked on this accidentally and is a bit shocked how many people not on some tiktok but here on SO want to _remove_ downvotes because they simple doesn't know how to treat them. A downvote is a way to mark that _a post_ is not _useful_. A signal that it _needs improvement_. Yes, downvote is embarassing a bit because that means our shiny post isn't really as shiny as we thought. But it's not a _personal_ threat. It's a completely different question if _some concrete people_ use it like that but is the bread knife guilty if someone use it for harm purposes? My 2 cents on this, no offence.

Comment: @AndriiM4n0w4R - well, the core of the whole debate is exactly the showdown between "feelings" and "curation". The far-left side says "to hell with curation if it hurts so much", the far-right - "to hell with feelings, curation justifies it". If one looks closely, they will notice this is a utilitarianism vs personalism debate. The issue is not helped by the former being the "silent majority", while the latter are the "vocal minority" as periodically a disgruntled user goes to meta and posts a disguised (or not-so) rant on abolishing downvotes, which surely triggers the rest (me included).

Comment: Can you folks please stop adding political subtext to this? Comparing this to a "political issue", or identifying stances as "far-left" or "far-right" feels *very* out of place and implies some rather unpleasant, inappropriate things.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - my apologies, I did not mean it in a "political" sense (if "far-left" and "far-right" came off as references to recent political struggles I admit this was a poor choice of words). I was talking about the moral philosophy dilemma which jumped at me at one point due to my background in philosophy (utilitarianism being a conservative idea after all). As for the "political issue", it is only referred to because of George's argument that you can't have a reasonable discussion about a "political" issue, so I am unsure how this notion can get a proper rebuttal without bringing it up.

Comment: @Braiam - pinging you as the author, but it is more a question to everyone - are we going to finalize this and make it a part of the FAQ properly, or did everyone simply move on and this will live as [faq-proposal] for the rest of eternity?

Comment: @OlegValter there are [faq proposals since '14.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251970/792066). I wouldn't worry too much. If and when there's renewed interest, something could happen. FAQ's usually ride on momentum to be tags as such.

Comment: @Braiam - yeah, I know that was more of a bump to see if there is any traction to officially adopt it since others start linking to it (as expected and welcome)...

Answer (score 54):

There are many reasons, but from having read many different meta posts from all over the network of Stack Exchange sites, including [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), there are several themes of the reasons for disagreements:

- **Already heard arguments for an already heard change**: since the sites existed, downvotes existed, and thus discussions about how to improve them. These proposals have been discussed for years and discussed from many angles. Discussing the same arguments, with the same solution and rehashing the same counter-arguments have gotten tiresome over the years. Whatever proposal you may have, you must research years of these discussions and show that you considered those discussions. Remember to read questions with all answers and comments.
- **Painting voters in a negative light**: this can be included in the above, but it comes so frequently and generates the strongest negative response that it deserves its own bullet point. **People respond poorly to being painted as lazy, malicious**, or with any other negative attribute. Voters are asked to give their honest opinion about posts, but when told that their honest opinion is nothing short of malicious or lazy or vindictive or petty, etc., they reject that outright. Imagine that for every action you do, thinking that you are doing right by the community, you are told that you are just doing it out of pettiness.
- **Despite all its faults, the site has been successful**: you need to bring strong evidence that the current system around voting is jeopardizing the site, that can't be attributed to...
- **Voting, in general, isn't done enough**: any limiting [requirement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/792066) has to take into consideration that for the model to work, [frequent and early voting is essential](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/). It's the only way that the system has to rate content.
- **There's one rule on voting**: don't target users. It's the only rule enforced by the system itself. If you aren't targeting a user, the system will let you vote however you like.
- **And yet, voters vote on content**: they try to collectively vote for the content itself, despite not being forced to. Users without accounts do the same since they are allowed to vote also, vote more frequently and are usually more critical of content. Presuming other reasons, dooms almost any argument about voting, since this is their purpose.

Comment: I tried to list the most important common themes. If I missed one, incorporate it into the post.

Comment: The main reason, for me, is that they often make many claims about what downvoting is/why people downvote/what it leads to that are not in line with the help center without backing this up with facts or research. That makes the "This does not show any research effort/is not useful" apply. If someone properly researched downvoting and found a good reason to change how downvotes worked, they might get an upvote from me.

Comment: One problem i find with a lot of posts where people want to "fix" the "toxicity" (uncited) of downvotes to make the site more "welcoming" is it's often (so not always) one sided against those downvotes, and doesn't address other "problems" that exist with the voting system, including upvotes. For example, they should also be addressing the problem of "welcoming" votes, which only serve to bubble crap to the top of the pile (uncited). They should probably address the "[meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/2029983)" as well, and anything else that they can think of.

Comment: "People respond poorly to be painted as lazy, malicious and other negative adjectives." That goes for those who write Qs and As but get "drive-by" DVs. We can't fix what we don't know about, and we can't fix what people can't agree is the problem, eg: too much research vs too little. I've been told I need to be more concise while also saying I'm missing info, by the same person, but then not explaining what's too verbose or what's missing. Consistency of voting is definitely not there, so it's not exactly useful in many cases.

Comment: Consistency is especially bad on legacy Qs that other's get marked as dupes, since old As have higher votes due to their age, yet currently relevant As aren't seen as easily, even though they are more relevant to current versions of software and languages. Voting needs a revamp on a couple of fronts, and it's because of the age of the site that makes it necessary, rather than it "aging well". The fact that's it's been talked about for so long should show that it's still broken and ignoring it because it's "tiresome" isn't a solution.

Comment: @computercarguy - excuse me, but how the consistency of voting is relevant to the point about people not liking being called "lazy", "malicious", "trolls", "unfriendly", "hostile", "toxic" and "cowards" (all cited per actual posts)? Not once in my life have I cast a vote without reading the post, or giving the poster the benefit of the doubt. My UV/DV ratio is 4.82 - and yet I find myself on the side of those who defend DV as a practice for 2 reasons: A. I see how voters are unjustly vilified. B. I am yet to see any suggestion of *improvement* rather than "I don't like it, let's abolish it".

Comment: voting *does* need a revamp, what it does not need is yet another accusation of being completely useless, harmful, and wielded by egotistical maniacs. Can we please stop mixing the problems of the voting system and half-baked attempts to vent some frustration on how one's posts have been received? I would *love* to have a nice discussion on possible changes to the voting system, there is a lot to talk about.

Comment: @OlegValter, you may not have voted that way, but I've seen people that have DVed 2-3x as many times as they UV. One I can remember was a medium RP member that had +20k DVs and every comment I read of theirs was about how they knew more about SE/SO than everyone else, so their "advice" should be followed to the letter. I have a Q where a 60k RP and 9k RP thinks similarly, but have opposing ideas what's "wrong". Since this is apparently widespread enough for it to be talked about for so many years, it's not an isolated incident or just for a few people. Consistency is definitely relevant.

Comment: @computercarguy - I do see your point, but there is a catch - with such a huge website run mostly by the community there bound to be problems like you described. I do think there are deep flaws in how we currently operate, how the reputation system works, etc. That said, what I am trying to get across is that this was a wrong discussion to take a stand on. When a thoughtful poster gets shut down for suggesting change, you have a sympathetic eye of others who also think that one is needed. This Q&A suggests accumulating and consolidating what we already discussed. Btw, I think it would be [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] a good idea to provide a balancing input on why people think downvotes are bad, so as the FAQ item is truly balanced. That might require extending the current effort to a more broad entry. However, this must be done impartially and with respect to the other position. If someone would champion such an *unbiased* addition, I would certainly support it.

Comment: @computercarguy Sure, people do respond negatively to that, but a major reason why we *have* downvotes is so you can express a negative opinion *without* being insulting. Much content is legitimately low quality, and it's nigh impossible to express the problem in words without the author taking it personally. That ought to be obvious by the fact so many people take downvotes (which don't contain such words) personally. At some point, you have to accept that some people (a lot of people) are going to feel bad when we do quality control, and you have to pick either quality of positive feelings.

Comment: @computercarguy Just a note "but I've seen people that have DVed 2-3x as many times as they UV" [there are only 10k users that have more downvotes than upvotes, meanwhile there are 355k users in the opposite way](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1381181) and this excludes users that haven't downvoted once.

Comment: @computercarguy It's also important to realize there's an asymmetry here: downvotes exist specifically for the purpose of addressing quality problems, so it's unavoidable that receiving one be associated with some negative connotations. We can try to mitigate that some, but we can't eliminate it. The act of *casting* a downvote, however, does not have such a condition as a prerequisite. We could certainly have a debate about whether downvotes are used properly (without disrespecting either side), but a post asserting that downvotes and downvoters are morally repugnant doesn't approach it.

Comment: @Braiam, I'm going to have to argue that base statistics, without comparisons, like that are nearly useless. It ignores how active those 10k are vs the 355k, how many people are borderline, or how many more DVs vs UVs there are total. I'm not even advocating about setting an arbitrary percent of DV vs UV is "good", but 10k people with more DVs than UVs seems excessive, even if it's "only" ~2.8%. For comparison, it may only take ~3.5% to overthrow a government. https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20190513-it-only-takes-35-of-people-to-change-the-world

Comment: @computercarguy - [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1381275) shows that a /s whopping /s 4.6% of voters with a positively received contribution in the last 6 months downvote more. Concrete breakdown on the activity of DVing users to UPing is nigh impossible to get, SEDE does not expose this data, but at least this is not anecdotal evidence about a personal experience - if anyone asked me, it is all moonlight and roses down here, but there are clues this is not the case. However, there is a difference between having signals of *issues* and being objectively *broken*.

Comment: @computercarguy at least is better than "but I've seen people that have DVed 2-3x as many times as they UV" which is purely anecdotal. Please, substain your affirmations with data. This discussion is _very_ inflammatory to begin with, but you are already calling for actions against "problem users". Bring data that demonstrate that it is a problem, not just observations.

Comment: @computercarguy You appear biased towards seeing people have more upvotes than downvotes. While it is concerning when the ratio between upvotes and downvotes is at the *far* extremes toward either side (and there are a lot of votes), there isn't a demarcation point where one ratio or another is good or bad. People use the site in different ways. They encounter different posts. Those users who are focusing on curation see a **far** higher percentage of poor quality posts than those who are just asking or answering questions, or who are just searching for answers, so more downvotes is "normal".

Comment: From what I've seen in these comments, and elsewhere where people discuss upvote/downvote ratios, both the vast majority of people and the numbers which are often stated as "good", "bad", or "normal", are *heavily* biased towards the ideal the person who's presenting the number has for how the site should be used, rather than looking at it with the understanding that the way which *they* experience and use the site *is not the same* as how every other person experiences and uses the site. There is no one "right" or "good" ratio, or even a narrow range of ratios which are "good", or "bad".

Comment: What this answer somehow misses is that it isn't downvotes that are needed -- they are a necessary evil. Its *curating content* thats needed. If someone can come up with a scheme that still allows content curation, but without downvotes, that would be worth exploring. But it needs to be well thought out and needs to be better then downvotes in order to replace them. But most discussions about downvotes are met with resistance not because we love downvotes -- but because the proposal would destroy the ability to *curate content*, and that is the ability that *must* be preserved - not downvotes.

Comment: @Polygnome that's not the purpose of this answer. This answer explain the common themes of why there's so much disagreement about "alter[ing] the way downvotes can be used". I try to keep the scope of this answer constrained to the way the question was asked, such that we don't have to repeat the same arguments several times.

Comment: @Polygnome I'm not sure "necessary evil" is a good way of phrasing it. If I'm offered tea or coffee and express my desire for tea, that's not subjecting coffee to "necessary evil". When I order my socks drawer with my favourite pair on top, I'm also not subjecting the rest of the socks to evil. This is simply how things are - when ordering items by some criteria, some need to go down the list. Assigning moral judgement of any form is when and why friction arises. I'd agree that there might be a better system that leads to less friction. Just don't want to further fuel the fire against this one

Comment: @Makyen, what I'd like to see is consistency in voting. I've had an Answer with +18, then voted closed. I got it reopened, but if 18 people think it's good and 3-5 think it bad, that's not consistent. This Q has +67/-24, so that's not consistent voting, either. Voting is all too often personal preference rather than rules based, or they think they understand the rules, but don't. Or the rules themselves are too broad and subjective. How much is "enough" research? IDK, and many other's don't, especially when people argue over it for CVs and reopening Qs. This whole Q is proof of that.

Comment: @computercarguy - let's separate meta and main voting patterns. Meta voting is like that because *we do not have any other way to express agreement/disagreement* with the poster. This is the limitation of the software we are using, not an indication of the voting inconsistency. Let's also separate close/delete and up/down voting - they are *separate* patterns, and while the question/answer can be upvoted, it *can* be closed/reopened. Let's also understand that posts are exposed to a huge number of *different* people with different views, levels of competency, tolerance and social skills. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] What is your experience with the site *may not* be the experience of others, so let us not extrapolate what we *personally* perceive is the case to the system as a whole. Voting is also influenced by the popularity of the tags and the general level of competence there (I already mentioned it). Frankly, *any* voting system suffers from that flaw.

Comment: "you must research years of these discussions and show that you considered those discussions. ... read questions with all answers and comments." - **this is just completely unreasonable**. Before posting a question you should do a Google search or two and quickly scan a few results. This is going to answer most questions if you're even remotely competent. You should not need to spend many hours reading through how-many-ever pages in full. If that's the only way to find the answer, then it means it's extremely poorly organised and the burden is on anyone who objects to these questions to fix it

Comment: @NotThatGuy - this is probably the best argument for providing a clear and concise explanation of the most common points brought up by these discussions :) Agreed that reading all questions/answers and comments seem way too harsh, though - no one sane enough (which, ironically, means I am quite insane) can read through a decade of back-and-forth in a reasonable time

Comment: @OlegValter, "let's separate meta and main voting patterns." The problem with that is you think other people do the same. I see plenty of Q's around many stacks that are DVed because people disagree with the premise or that it should have even been asked, with nothing else wrong with it. And there's enough of these that it's more than just low RP members not knowing what a vote means. That's what I mean about voting consistency. I also see comments for "Why the close votes? This is a good Q" on quite a few Qs, especially lately.

Comment: @computercarguy - I was explicitly replying to "his Q has +67/-24, so that's not consistent voting, either" - meta should not be mixed with main when the argument is about voting consistency. When the whole point of the meta UV/DV voting is to express agreement/disagreement (shortcomings of the software aside), it is expected to have divisive voting counts. I understand what you mean, but I replied to this as well already: "posts are exposed to a huge number of different people with different views, levels of competency, tolerance and social skills" [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] we can't expect everyone to fall in line and be the best judges of the situation. Hence the need for better onboarding, education, and quality control checks. For a community-driven project, some level of inconsistency is expected. Besides, you and I are just 2 users, our experience is neither universal nor representative - some stacks fare better, some worse. Some tags are lovingly curated, some are a hot mess due to a number of factors.

Comment: [3/3] high reputation count is also, as I am sure you know, not a guarantee that someone knows how the site operates, what is good curation, how to approach other users, etc. Moreover, what you refer to is anecdotal evidence, frankly, it can't be used to justify whether the problem is significant or widespread (note that I am not saying it isn't). We can go case-by-case if you want and take a look if the closure/downvoting was justified - but otherwise, we can't draw any conclusions from it.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I doubt many of these post survived, also the hope is that readers are aware that this feature has been discussed too many several <add more superlatives> times before. Meta regulars remember many of these, and the lack of novelty will set the user to fail, because someone will close it against <some easily found duplicate that was asked 30 months ago>.

Comment: @Braiam I'm ironically too lazy to go and find that post again to see exactly what happened and whether it was closed as a duplicate of an actually appropriate question eventually, but one of the major criticisms of the treatment of that question was closing it as a duplicate of an only-vaguely-related question. That's really not a fair response. To be a duplicate, the linked question actually needs to address their specific points raised in the question (whether directly or indirectly). 1/2

Comment: @Braiam I empathise with the knee-jerk response to just want to get rid of something seen many times before, posted by someone who showed a lack of respect by not putting in the work to ask a properly researched question. In fact, I hate duplication more than most. But that doesn't mean the response is *reasonable*, both in terms of wanting to get rid of it at all, and in terms of *how* we actually get rid of it (i.e. there needs to be a proper canonical duplicate, or a similar enough non-canonical duplicate, if we want to go that route). 2/2

Comment: Is there any resource with links to all the discussions on downvotes and the main arguments and counterarguments? If not, is there anyone who would be willing to pull together a wiki of sorts for this? It would make it much easier for people to know exactly what research needs to be done before they should contribute their ideas.

Comment: @ProQ such arguments are out there, usually in deleted questions. Most of them are what I've remember have read in the last 6-8 years in meta.

Answer (score 22):

So, you are here because you proposed some change to voting, especially proposed to limit or remove downvoting at all, and you got a strong negative reaction from the meta community, probably lots of downvotes and maybe close and delete votes as well and you want to know why?

**Downvotes are important for content selection**

Additionally to the [answer by Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405700/1536976) I think I can give you some important insight and I think that this insight is that if you speak about downvotes you absolutely must be aware of the impact of downvotes on content selection. Downvotes on the main sites effectively suppress bad content and that is such a useful feature, maybe the main feature of downvotes and without alternative. It's extremely important especially if you are curating the content, i.e. managing and organizing it.

**How do downvotes select content?**

How is this achieved? Downvotes directly only influence the number that is displayed next to a contribution, but that again influences other things. The default sort order is a ranking of that number and top ranked contributions get much more attention, bottom ranked contributions much less. Readers typically are biased by the number, i.e. take it as a prior quality/popularity assessment. A negative score can lead to automatic removal of content and a lowered score also lowers reputation, which can lead to a loss of privileges even up to the ability to ask further questions. Downvotes have arguably a deterrent effect on the amount of future content creation.

**Active users on meta are managing content using downvotes and love them**

Active users on meta are organizing and managing the content of Stack Overflow much more likely than the average user and there is lots of bad (low quality) content produced every day and downvotes are very useful in suppressing this bad content. Naturally, it will be a beloved feature here.

**If there was no bad content or somebody else would manage the content...**

If there was an alternative way to suppress bad content (a secret algorithm maybe like the Google search algorithm that simply decides what is good and what is not) or if there was only good content produced because people would put an awful lot of carefulness into the preparation of their content, maybe people would see the need for downvotes less, but such things do not exist currently.

**It's still a compromise**

Yes, people here know about the downsides of downvotes, mistakes in voting, negative feelings when you receive some, which might lower motivation of contributors that could otherwise contribute useful content, but the general idea is that the benefits by far outweigh the disadvantages.

**How to really propose changes about downvotes**

So, if you think something should be done about downvotes and want to present the idea here, you better gather a lot of eloquent arguments, do a great amount of research before (to not just repeat what others have said before), are open to discussions and learning from others and come with modesty. And even then it will be an uphill battle.

Comment: I agree with the general gist of the answer, but if this is to be a FAQ entry, I think it'd help if the answer was split up in some subsections, to make it more readable (It's a bit of a wall of text now)

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, it's a bit long for mainly only a single point. I tried to make it more readable by adding section headers.

Comment: That's much better :D

Comment: I guess this answers addresses the general question "what are downvotes for"

Comment: @Braiam More like "Why people around here love downvotes", which is probably the first step to understand why a possible change proposal hasn't worked. It was also designed to give an idea how to make a better proposal next time. A better proposal would probably explain how people can achieve what they want to alternatively.

Comment: We don't need downvotes, let's just show both of the current votes, the upvotes with a header "This question/answer is useful" and the downvotes with a header "This question/answer is not useful". Both would have positive number, no negative votes can be seen anymore, and everybody will be happy ... Then we also would have two reps, one for useful posts, and another for not useful posts, both always above zero. Everything under the hood would work like it always has worked, only that you can't see any negative scores on the site.

Comment: @Teemu - an interesting take on the psychology of voting, I think it actually *can* help, because it certainly seems like the side that wants to abolish downvoting talks more about *feelings* DVs incite, and the other side appeals to *curation needs*. The situation is not helped since we are conditioned to think "green is good, red is bad", "addition is good, subtraction is bad" throughout our lives, and not only rep is deduced for being downvoted, it is also colored red. It is also a relatively cheap solution which makes it more likely to actually be implemented

Comment: @Oleg Both of the numbers shown in neutral grey, of course. Then we could also see hilarious comments like: "_I'm voting up this post in the category of not useful_".

Comment: @Teemu - certainly hilarious :) Joking aside, this form already feels more lighthearted and less confrontational (which, I guess, is one of the main reasons for the whole drama around downvotes) - although I am sure people will find a way to become upset about anything.

Comment: @Teemu "Everything under the hood would work like it always has worked, only that you can't see any negative scores on the site." Would help those that are allergic to negative numbers, but otherwise it wouldn't take very long before people would mentally add the minus sign. A more serious proposal might be to for example not show the score below a certain threshold, say -1 on the main sites. Who really cares if a question or answer is at minus 10 or minutes 20, it's dead anyway.

Comment: @Trilarion - true, not a silver bullet by any means. Not "kicking a dead horse" should also help, especially if combined with the above. It both caters to the content curation side since votes are still recorded and to the "feelings" side since users do not plummet into the abyss of peer disapproval. With improvements to onboarding and the overall guidance, this could very well lead to a *positive* change for a change (pun intended).

Comment: @Trilarion That is an option too (wasn't it even tested on the site a couple of years ago?). But when having two reps, you could see the all time "positive" rep you've earned, the "negative" doesn't even have to be public, it could be placed in the private data shown on the Profile page. That might keep a new user in good mood, when their hard-work-earned rep doesn't just vanish because of a single poor question.

Comment: [1,2] `Downvotes have arguably a deterrent effect on the amount of future <substandard> content creation` Feels like might need that additional qualifier in there? `If there was an alternative way to suppress bad content (a secret algorithm maybe like the Google search algorithm that simply decides what is good and what is not) ` - Whilst we may not always know why a question/answer was downvoted, enough downvotes we can use the site ethos to guide us and feel confident it is our peers giving us a heads up (ignoring the issue of older questions tending to have more votes).

Comment: [2,2]  My stomach turns a little at the thought of a community run site having some secret algorithm determining content quality on our behalf. We know that visibility and engagement are key for the health of meta and stack* . Who else should curate the content we rely on and contribute to? And in many cases, care about? You'd never afford the staffing to manage the current workload, and back to line one re:algos.

Comment: @Trilarion how do you propose to visualize Reps in a clear way then? Not the number .- but the reasoning why User A is allowed to do X and User B is _not_ allowed to do X because well - User B has far more less usefull posts so the rep he has is lower and hence his interaction possibilities are different. And frankly there is a difference between a -1 post and a -8 post, especially for fresh content which we want to curate. If a post collects 8 DV in the same timespan others collect 1 (maybe driveby, whatever) it tells you loads about the question or answer.

Comment: @QHarr "Who else should curate the content we rely on and contribute to?" I agree with you, I feel safest with the current method. But I'm also programmer enough to dislike manual work and inventing algorithms to replace that work fully or partly has a certain appeal. Anyway, most of the visitors to Stack Overflow come through search engines and they may or may not regard the numbers printed next to the content. We keep duplicates because they are search magnets. If score and number of visits correlate, they might be exchangeable. I don't think we should stop voting though.

Comment: @PatrickArtner "If a post collects 8 DV in the same timespan others collect 1..." A score of -1 is sometimes repairable, i.e. if the question has a minor flaw, which gets repaired, it can make the turnaround. The difference between score -7 and score -8 is negligible, the question is dead. The idea here was simply to replace the display of scores smaller than say -1 with "<-1" because there isn't much useful signal contained in these numbers. It would be pure cosmetics and as such maybe the smallest possible change. Even that already feels like a big leap, doesn't it.

Comment: We are entrenched in our local optimum and I guess that the chances that any proposal that limits downvotes somehow is approved by the community is really exactly 0. The current debate is more about under which conditions we should have discussions about it and I fully support that people need to make an effort if they want a discussion about such a topic. The greater danger is however that the company might decide to just switch off that downvote button for good one day. They aren't dependent on meta approval. One more or less discussion on meta might only be a small thing compared to that.

Comment: @Trilarion SE/SO ran an experiment about a year and a half ago(?) with limiting the displayed score to basically what you're talking about. I'd suggest you search here on MSO to find the various posts describing what was done and the results.

Comment: @Makyen I know. I asked for [the results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393907/what-were-the-results-of-the-a-b-experiment-where-negative-question-scores-were) but didn't really get a detailed result. They didn't get a clear outcome but it also wasn't clear what their initial question was, they hadn't said. The experiment was a bit different, they clamped the score to zero instead to -1 or another score, they also omitted the "<", which made it a questionable practice. And they did not announce the experiment resulting in lots of bug report questions on meta. I remember it well.

Comment: @Tril I will look at a -1 to -3 Post in topic I know about - I wont do it for -8 ones. Mainly to see if they can be salvaged, need to be dupe-hammered or might have gotten a -1 driveby vote that was IMHO not warranted. So displaying <-1 will waste my time and make curating harder.

Answer (score 11):

Many of such proposals miss or ignore the purpose of downvoting and the purpose of  the whole site.

### Purpose of the site

The goal SO aims is that once you isolate and describe the problem you are facing, a search will show an already asked question with your problem stated (asked by someone who had similar problem earlier) and that question will already have answers that fit you.

### Purpose of voting

Not all users put the same effort to isolate the problem and search for solution. So there are probably many questions with similar problem, some of them better worded, some of them a bit unclear. Also each one may have multiple answers, some of them more useful, some less useful, some even harmful. You don't want to read all of them and evaluate each answer. You need some content rating. And on SO this is done by voting. Those, who read an answer and find it useful, upvote it (at least some of readers do it). Those, who find some answer not useful, downvote them. If a problem is stated in two questions and one of them is poorly worded and unclear, it will get downvoted and the other one upvoted, encouraging answerers to answer the question with better quality <sup>1</sup>. As a result there is a chance that you will have to read one question with few good answers sorted at the top, instead of gazilion questions each having gazilion answers, all with unknown quality.

### Back to your proposal

If the proposal does not address above purposes and does not explain how to achieve them in different way, it will not be received positively.
If you disagree with above purposes or don't think they are important, you should start discussion about *this* first, not start discussion about downvotes that assume those purposes are not important.
If you suggest some better way to achieve content rating, without using downvotes, I believe your proposal will be better received.

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact one of the questions should be closed as a duplicate of the other, but it is a separate process.

Comment: Interesting that this answer tries to give "Purpose of the site" which isn't very similar to "create a library of high quality programming questions"

Comment: @Braiam - well, the core still seems to be there, maybe it will be more understandable to the target audience of such a FAQ entry (after all, what else library is for if not to be useful to others) as (probably) curators should already have this goal as an axiom

Comment: @SebastianSimon Is it now better? Feel free to improve if you have ideas. English is not my native language.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Neither is it mine.  It’s good now.

Answer (score 4):

I can summarise it as such: don't create meta posts in the form of "downvotes bad, people hate them, remove them".

At least... **not yet**. It is too soon. And that is not specifically to do with downvotes either but any existing system; they were all designed with a purpose in mind, a problem to solve. They were not created just to hinder and annoy people. They were not created by stupid people who did not know what they were doing, quite the contrary.

Fact of the matter is that despite its overwhelming success, Stack Overflow is not a self-sustaining knowledge base; it needs a *lot* of human intervention, unfortunately. Curation and content rating being the two usual suspects, they make or break the success of this site which is that you can find answers to questions or to find questions to answer. And for that to keep happening now and in the future, good, relevant questions and answers need to be first in line in search results. Good questions need to be answered and bad questions need to be either fixed or go somewhere else. For good questions to be answered they need to be not hidden away behind a mountain of bad questions.

And therein lies the problem; before you can open a narrative about restricting or removing features which allow that curation and/or content rating, the self-sustainability needs to be drastically improved first. Hence why I say: too soon, Don't sell the hide before the bear is shot. Any ideas on how to do *that* in particular can be very welcome indeed. If you want a Stack Overflow without downvotes then you will need to design a Stack Overflow where it is possible to have no downvoting while you can still find good answers to questions, or find good questions to answer. That is likely not going to happen in one sweep, it'll need to happen in smaller improvement steps; steps we can comprehend, agree on, measure and tweak if necessary.

But which steps? Or maybe back up one step further... what do we need to know to be able to define those steps? Good questions. Hard questions.

Comment: Side note: Although I value the existing answers, to me they focus a little too much on explaining yet again why voting exists and is necessary. I thought I'd take a slightly different approach, as an addendum to that valuable information.

Answer (score -8):

> Why is there such disagreement when the concept of changing downvotes is raised?

Part of it is because the identity of the site is rooted in those initial mechanics including downvotes.

If you've spent the last 13 years downvoting and believing downvotes solve problems, of course you're going to be upset when someone says "They cause more problems than they solve, and therefore should be eliminated".

This is exactly the sort of political issue that won't be solved through reason; and that makes any discussion about it difficult to have.

There's 13 years of inertia around the idea that downvotes are a requirement, and that's going to create a stiff headwind towards any discussion on changing that.

Another part of it is a lack of frame of reference for a better approach.  Downvoting meets a need that people have; and there's not yet been a suggestion that allays the downvoter advocates' fears; and therefore the effect is "we can't possibly continue to discuss this since this is the best there is".

We're getting meta-meta at this point, talking about the problem with talking about the problem; but these are the sorts of conversations a community needs to be able to have, because the conversation here will shape how we talk about the problems (like downvoting) going forward.

Comment: There is only one issue I have with the post - it is overtly biased against downvoting as it is worded right now and would benefit from a more neutral point of view (only in the scope of providing input on why such proposals are met with harsh disagreement). That said, these proposals *do* seem to hit a nerve, and not in the least because the practice has been around for more than a decade usually without bringing forth anything that would take the best of both worlds: keep the benefits and avoid the pitfalls of downvoting.

Comment: Isn't this covered under the "Despite all its fault, the site has been successful" heading on the other answer? If there's a problem with voting, it is because "in general, isn't done enough". Why aren't upvotes a problem too, if they are the counterpart of downvotes?

Comment: If after 13 years one of the fundamental governing principles of the site is still not understood (slightly different from accepted), it feels to me like a severe communication failure from SO.

Comment: Evidence for this theory: you'll never see an argument for why downvoting is useful, only the argument that the community *believes* it's useful and therefore it should be kept. And as I've said many times, I don't accept that the community that believes downvotes are useful is representative of the community as a whole when you include all the users who have been bullied off the site by the old guard. I believe those disaffected users are numerous because they turn out in droves to complain whenever SO is mentioned on other sites.

Comment: Evidence against this theory: you'll never see an argument for why downvoting is not useful, only the argument that a user *believes* it's not useful and therefore it should be abolished. See what I did there? Both are *statements* that require data and arguments to be substantiated, they are not axioms. Also: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405700/11407695), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369364/11407695), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340180/11407695), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390571/11407695). These are from spending 5 mins to look for. True, those who [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] believe downvotes are useful are not *the whole* community. But the same is true on the other hand - the other party is *also* not representative of the whole community. This is why it is important to have *productive* discussions about the voting systems every once in a while (hell, I think even decoloring the downvotes will go a long way in making them feel not "unwelcoming"), but it is also important to differentiate between those that have potential to bring change from those that do not have one from the get-go.

Comment: "This is exactly the sort of political issue that won't be solved through reason; and that makes any discussion about it difficult to have." This is insulting and toxic. You're essentially declaring your opponents to be irrational, despite the fact that many solid arguments about the benefits of downvoting have been given over the years. Perhaps it is *that* attitude, which seeks to ignore when your detractors have a point, that is creating problems.

Comment: gnat looking at [site traffic stats](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) saying "11m visits/day". Hmmm if this is inertia then it seems to be of the kind worth keeping

Comment: We have a theory that says downvotes is useful, one I've yet to see someone rebuff convincingly, and we have _some_ evidence it's working with 11m visits/day, but the only way people may oppose its abolition is because they lack reason?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede isn't that covered in the other answer? "Despite all its fault, the site has been successful".

Comment: @gnat - in George's defense, I don't think they referred to "inertia" in any sense other than "with 13 years of downvoting renouncing the practice is an idea one would hardly entertain". That said, for a "deeply flawed" site we are doing pretty good

Comment: I'm getting the distinct sense that commenters lack an understanding of what "political issue" or "political question" actually means.   In this context, it means that it comes down to what the people in power want, vs what the cold hard facts or data says.  It'll change based on who's in power. That's a political question, not a value judgment.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - no one is saying the issue is not political. What is argued is that you have an incorrect notion of what "a political issue" means by reducing it to "sentiment" checks and whim of those "who's in power". Frankly, it is a bit insulting to be considered so out of touch to not get that "in real life" there is no such thing as pure "hard fact or data". What is desirable is to have an *educated* and *reasonable* discussion, which is *not helped* by rehashing the same on *both sides*. If all we want to measure "sentiments", we can run a poll without spending days on end arguing.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker If you feel you have been misunderstood, the traditional response on SO is to edit your content to clarify. That said, your comment constitutes a general argument against having any discussion of the issue at all. If it's correct, then there is *nothing* to be gained by debating the merits or drawbacks of the feature on Meta, as only the whims of the company matter, and any post doing so ought to be deleted as a drama creating waste of time.

Comment: @QHarr "If after 13 years one of the fundamental governing principles of the site is still not understood .. it feels to me like a severe communication failure from SO." Well, just recently they started some research into downvoting. Who knows, maybe they will discover some good reasons for why downvoting is a key factor.

Comment: @OlegValter "..we can run a poll" We do all the time. All that voting is equivalent to polling or not? Maybe on meta we should have discussions on controversial topics like this one without votes at all.

Comment: @Trilarion - I was specifically referring to the idea about "measuring sentiments" once in a while as not meriting going out of our way to escalate any post of type "downvotes are bad, let's get rid of them" to martyrdom and then proceeding to walk in circles for a couple of days, that's all (and yeah, we do these polls all the time by voting). Off-note: I am curious about the results of the DV research as well. Besides, some issues users have with DVs might be solved by the upcoming change to the onboarding experience), but that's not a given.

Comment: I reject the premise that we're doing anyone any favors by coddling them with a lack of negative feedback. I also have seen nothing, and I mean *nothing*, in any discussion of this topic that would indicate that we can effectively *enforce norms without it*. Not even a fig leaf of wishful thinking a la "it'll work itself out". Instead, it always seems to be an attack on the norms themselves. That's why people get so heated about this, we are in effect being told "your culture is wrong". Which is about as well received as one would expect.

Comment: @JaredSmith "..we can [not] effectively enforce norms without it..." Good point. Any discussion would have to start with what are the best ways to enforce norms. This should then be ontopic. Maybe we can learn from parenting. Bringing kids to obey norms is an established problem and afaik penalties alone do not result in the best outcome. Guidance, being a good example, .. also plays a role. Maybe we should think about DVs on a more fundamental level as part of an integrated strategy to achieve our goal.

Comment: @Trilarion agreed. I would be all for a DV alternative that preserved the things DVs are supposed to preserve. And per this answer, maybe DVs have outlived their time and their usefulness, but I never see it broached from a perspective of what would serve the function they were intended to serve. Just "oh noes, the downvotes hurt my tiny little feelings, so since the problem *obviously* can't be with *me* they must just all be toxic cowardly malicious jerks".

Comment: George, this is really strange. As far as I know, SO is one of the only platform in which the concept of downvote exists, and in the ones where it doesn't, such as Facebook, Twitter or Quora, I think we can agree that wrong content is not marked as such in any way. I absolutely don't know how you could achieve that without the downvote, so I believe that I fit your description of "can't think there's another, better solution" because I haven't ever seen one in action, or even **heard** about one.

Comment: I mean, Facebook and Twitter have lately single handedly banned thousands of accounts, content creators and stuff because they were wreaking havoc with disinformation. I would bet that, have there been a way to downvote content on either of those platform, that would have been mitigated by the very users of those platforms.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I think you're reading more into my argument than exists. The question asks "Why do people have such a hard time allowing discussion on the subject" and the comments I received on this answer prove the argument I make in my answer: that people have a hard time allowing the discussion because they're attached to downvotes, and they feel like any disgreement with downvotes is an attack on their identity vis a vis Stack Overflow.  It's interesting to watch.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - "prove" is really pushing it. If anyone takes a look at the "comments on this answer", most of them address that "these are the sorts of conversations" is directed at the *wrong* type of posts and that there is nothing wrong in having a *real* conversation about voting. Since I am the one who provided a chunk of those "comments", it is also interesting to watch how "attachment to downvotes" is being read into them and then presented as a fact. For what it's worth, I think your answer is on point - 13 years does lead to substantial inertia, but this is *precisely* [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] why rehashing the same arguments over and over will not lead to anything but empty bickering and hurt feelings on both sides.

Comment: What bothers me is by endorsing such pseudo-conversations we give those who are *really* in charge of any substantial change - the company itself - we, ironically, give them a copout to improve the public image of the platform with the lowest amount of effort. Instead of striving to provide a civil critique of how the software works (and I firmly believe that we would not have to rehash this over and over if not for the shortcomings of it) we devolve into fruitless, lengthy and tiresome "discussions" about the oppression of opinion, etc

Comment: FWIW, apparently it's still necessary to [dump this on twitter](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/628507458910027777/817343004951838730/unknown.png), out of context, where we can't defend ourselves, unless we're specifically stalking george there. (@jpmc26)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I don't appreciate being pilloried on a platform I don't even belong to and that is well known for generating outrage by people who have so little understanding of SO's platform that they actually believe its model to be racist. I wasn't upset that you called it a "political issue." I was upset that you appeared to be calling others unreasonable for supporting the downvote feature, and it appears I wasn't the only one who thought that's what you meant. I don't like the bad faith assumption that the only reason people do so is because we've been doing it a long time, either.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker My understanding was also driven by that bad faith assumption immediately preceding the remark. Your comment seemed to suggest I had misunderstood. That's why I suggested you edit to clarify, especially in light of the fact I wasn't alone. I still encourage you to do so, since we have identified a specific, narrow source of confusion. I also hope you'll amend your Twitter thread with an admission that *you* misunderstood *my* words, as your representation there is not even remotely accurate, although I can't identify in what way I might have been unclear.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not going to retract or edit words I didn't say.  This seems to stem from you putting words into what I said that weren't there.  I said: "We cant have a reasonable conversation about this", to which your reply was to immediately castigate me as insulting you as irrational.  If that doesn't prove to you that we can't have a reasonable conversation on the topic of downvotes; I don't think anything can.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I literally admitted that I seemed to have misunderstood, and I responded to your comment above with a *rational* response about what your clarified argument implied. I consider that evidence that we *are* capable of having a reasonable discussion. You're the one insisting we can't and refusing to admit you misunderstood what I wrote, and you're unwilling to clarify your post to help your readers understand better despite having extreme specifics on where that understanding went wrong.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - albeit I wouldn't phrase that so harshly, in the tweet you do seem to misrepresent the issue the comment takes with your quote as the issue with "calling something a political issue", while the objected part is with the "that won't be solved through reason" part. As already mentioned multiple times, no one (at least I hope) is arguing the issue is not political, it is argued that political issues can and *should* be reasoned about without devolving into sentiment analysis