How can I improve my understanding and application of what makes a better question?
I've asked a question (now migrated) that has had two downvotes and no upvotes. As such, I'd like some feedback to help me ask better questions in the future to help others provide answers. My belief is that I've adhered to the guidelines for asking questions:

I have provided a good question title and added tags that are relevant to the question.
Reading the Meta post on How do I ask a good question?, I believe my question is on topic, suitable, researched to the best of my ability, and searched on site. I'll admit, this is not a direct programming question, and is not totally reproducible in its current state, but is related to associated tools.
I'm giving links that show I'm looking for an answer before posting a question.
The question is well-presented, clear, and doesn't present opinions.
Given the wealth of questions on that topic spanning years, it's clear this is a persistent problem with a wide range of causes and resolutions.
I'm engaging with questions in the comments, in order to provide additional information.

I'd even edited the question to remove some 'emotive' language in there, based on spending two days on trying to fix what seems like every tool I've been using.
I can accept that downvotes are just as likely as upvotes. Though, given my question hasn't had much traction, no answers, and two downvotes, there must be elements that don't align with what the community expects.
How could I edit my question further to better align with SO's expectations?

Your question has upwards of 15 comments, the majority of which, seek clarification.  Your question has received zero edits.  Address the feedback which you have received.

--general-log will provide additional information required to answer your question more than likely. Others have had the same problem in the past with the InnoDB plugin

@SecurityHound I did do that, but the edit history appears to have been lost during the migration of the question. You can see at the points I've made clarifying updates at least.

This question suggests your error is caused by mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1 but your original question on SO does not mention if that question's answer was helpful.

@SecurityHound I'm not seeing that same log line as the question asker, and it would be for a different MySQL version on a different macOS version. It's the same error, but seemingly a different cause as I elude to. Still, I'll look into it.

There isn't much point in trying to understand how to improve the question to fit SO. It's not a programming question, you can't make that fit no matter how much it is polished.

Well in this case (and I've closed thousands of questions) the fact is your question seems to be off-topic at SO and it'll be much likelier to get a good answer and be useful in the future at the dba.se site. So you'll need to add "verify the Q is on-topic at the given site" to the checklist - and all of this stuff can be confusing for new users. But it does seem to have turned out well this time. Cheers!

In general, a good question-asking strategy is also a good debugging strategy. If you approach the question the way you would debugging (isolating problems, gathering and recording information, making and testing observations, etc...) you'll write good questions. And rarely ask them because you solved the problem in the process.

@SecurityHound It had quite some revisions on Stack Overflow (if a question is migrated, the history isn't, but the revision history is linked in the migration, see the "revisions" link in the "Post migrated here" note in the revision history on DBA)

I think you're already well on your way to be honest. First of all, you're asking the right question - how to improve rather than "what gives". Second of all, you did not hone in specifically on downvotes like pretty much everyone else does, you identified that not receiving upvotes is important too. And you read the help center and can link to specific resources. The next step is to read through meta to be honest. A very good way to find out what not to do is to look at meta posts about downvotes and closed questions. They have the winning answers.

Gotta say that's a question about tools programmers use, and it's not in a system admin perspective, so from my perspective it definitely belongs on Stack Overflow. Yes, you can get an answer on DBA.stackexchange.com but that's not a DBA centric question, unless DBAs start using Macbook Pros for their Database Servers.  Heck, the top answer is even "use Docker", which no DBA in their right mind would recommend out of the gate.
The migrators got this one wrong; but the advice is still good: Respond to feedback, and make the problem reproducible (or at least give the steps you took).

A few (general) observations: 1) the likelihood of getting an upvote for a good question (in line with the SO guidelines) is substantially less than the likelihood of getting a downvote if your question is below par, hence a general negative bias; 2) anonymously doing a small easy nasty thing, like an unfounded silent downvote, is tempting for many people (applies to the internet as a whole); 3) silent downvotes are not actionable (comments are, closures are), that's why I believe users who do that are not motivated to improve the quality of questions on SO

To be clear, I have no idea whether anything of what I said applies to the OP's question. If there were useful comments explaining the reasons for downvoting the question (as some suggest here in the comment section), this case is different

At any rate, I believe we should discontinue the downvote feature as it is not helpful for SO and harmful for learners who rely on this platform to gain knowledge. I'll go as far as saying that helping new people enter the field and improve their lives is more important than (should be prioritized over) keeping SO clean from "bad" questions. Though, again, downvoting doesn't help either case

@Powet you're thinking help desk. Stack Overflow isn't a help desk. It's a library, and library becomes useless because searchers can't find the information they need through all of the noise. While I'm sure there are some fools out there who just want to crush souls, the rest of us want a good measure of the value of a question so we can curate the library efficiently and effectively.

@Powet "I believe we should discontinue the downvote feature as it is not helpful for SO and harmful for learners who rely on this platform to gain knowledge." Except that SO is not for learning. It is a QNA platform and a library of QNA, to help professional programmers and hobbyists get their answers to their questions. It is not a platform to encourage or discourage learning. It has nothing to do with educating to begin with.

"I'll go as far as saying that helping new people enter the field and improve their lives is more important than (should be prioritized over) keeping SO clean from "bad" questions." That statement contradicts the main purpose of this site. It is not to help new people get into programming but to help programmers get answers to their programming questions and maintaing a high-quality, clean repository of such answers. It is as simple as that.

@user4581301 Precisely. If a library is full of low-quality BS, it becomes a problem finding the good stuff. That's the reason SO cares a lot about downvoting off-topic questions, closing duplicates, the review queues, etc.

@SyedM.Sannan there are a lot of assumptions in your comment. To name a few: 1) if a question is downvoted, it's low-quality; 2) downvotes effectively protect against off-topic questions; 3) the SO community cares about downvoting and wants it to stay. I believe all of those assumptions are, at best, questionable

@Powet 1. No-reason or targetted downvotes are not non-existent but rare, to say the least. Downvoting more is actually encouraged by the site's policies as it is an effective way to keep good quality content.

They don't "protect", in the sense that nothing except  pre-emptively banning the question poster would "protect" the posting of off-topic questions. However, they are a good way to convey that X types of questions are not welcomed on the platform and the OP, as well as other users are able to learn that, which they actually should have before posting the question.



Oh, not really. The community is overwhelmingly against removing the downvote feature: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405699/why-are-proposed-changes-to-voting-which-limit-or-remove-the-use-of-downvotes . Downvoting more is usually good. Because more often than not, the questions (or answers for that matter) don't deserve to be there. It would not be wrong to claim that most of the new content on SO is either off-topic, or duplicate material and in turn, most of the votes are rightfully downvotes.


@Powet More of these: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369362/why-even-have-downvotes/369364#369364 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340174/do-we-really-need-reputation-and-upvotes-downvotes/340180#340180 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390567/lets-reframe-voting/390571#390571

@SyedM.Sannan note, SO already has that arrangement for comments. For example, if you don't like this comment, you can't downvote it. On the other hand, if you believe it violates one or more of SO rules, you can report it citing a specific reason. I believe it can work just as well for questions

@Powet The purpose of comments is not to add content, so content rating mechanisms naturally aren’t needed as for posts.

Compared to a question or answer, comments are ridiculously easy to delete if the community finds it necessary, but what you will often see is a poorly thought out comment receiving a rebuttal a comment or two later, and that rebuttal is heavily upvoted.

Side note: Stack Overflow is a rough place for beginners because there is almost nothing a beginner can ask about an established language that has not already been asked and answered. A well-written duplicate question can serve as an excellent landing page directing future searchers to the existing question, but if the question is not well-written it's not useful.

It should be perfectly normal that for novices Stack Overflow is pretty much read-only, it is a natural side effect of how the site operates and its current maturity. That is one of the things that makes the site hard to understand. Things really are very different now than how things were in 2008. Not only the rules have changed a lot, but its also... filled. We have come to a point where IF the site keeps being used as originally intended, your question belongs in another castle. Because this castle already has the answer tucked away somewhere. And that hurts if your mission is ad income.


I believe my question is on topic

This is the issue. Unless you are getting the error when you try to use the database from code, and not otherwise, I see nothing in the migrated question that makes it about programming. While programmers commonly use databases, so do non-programmers - which is why sites like dba.SE exist at all.
To recap the gold standard from the on-topic link:


a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development


The first three are combined with "or", and that group is combined with the last point with "and". The question must be unique to software development, and must also fall in at least one of the previous three categories.
I note your question is upvoted on dba.SE, where it belongs. I personally think it could still be improved - in particular: please explicitly state the conditions under which you get the error. Do you mean that you see this while trying to install the database using brew? Or do you mean that you successfully used this tool to install the database, (believe that this fact is relevant to the problem,) and now get this error when using the database? In the latter case, what kind of use is required to trigger the error?

I disagree with your answer because DBAs don't administor MySQL on Macbook Pros. So yea, while they concievably have a local database; they certainly can't be expected to be knowledgable about MySQL on MBP.  Whereas programmers often need local database servers and they commonly use MBPs as their development machines. This is squarely a "tool programmers use" in a context that makes it perfect for a programming site.

@GeorgeStocker There is no reason given here as to why the hardware is relevant to the question; and if it were, that would still not rescue the question.

@KarlKnechtel the hardware isn’t relevant but the operating system is, and on Macs, the operating system is MacOS. Please let me know how many DBAs administer their company’s databases on MacOS and I’ll reconsider my position.

That doesn't change the objection. It just increases the likelihood of having a question for apple.SE instead.

That's even more problematic.  Refusing to allow a question that is demonstrably about tools programmers use and is best at home on Stack Overflow to its context, folks that completely ignoring that for anything else about the question that they can maybe indirectly say it shouldn't be on Stack Overflow when contextually there's no place better to get an answer to this particular problem.  This is one of those cases where folks are harmed by an over-stringent interpretation of what Stack Overflow is for.

Programmers equally well "commonly use", say, MS Paint. The fact that someone is drawing an art asset for inclusion in a GUI doesn't make it a question about programming. Again, the fact that DBAs don't commonly use a MacBook Pro to administer a MySQL database does nothing to make a database administration question into a programming question. There is nothing in the question that suggests the answer would be fundamentally different because of the operating system; the goal is simply to administer the database. And the first answer offered suggests using a platform-agnostic container.

Ah yes, the 'ol "If a programmer needs to store data, why didn't they think of MS Paint" argument.

@GeorgeStocker To be totally honest, it no longer comes across that you are engaging in good faith here, or willing to consider other points of view. I think we're done here.
